# Add checkboxes at runtime and save them in HTML file code

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create an html (with javascript) file where I'd like to add/remove checkboxes at runtime, save them in the html code so that they are available when the file is opened next time. I do not want to use use a server (so no JSP or PHP).

Please tell me whether it is possible just by using javascript? If it is, please point to resources where I can get more information about it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using [HTML5 local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) or even [client database storage](http://www.aquim.com/web-article-237.html). If you don't know whether the browser supports them yet, another possibility is to use persistent cookies.

Comment: Thanks Darin, but I am not sure which browser the end user would be using, so I can;t go with HTML 5 browser limitation.

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer. In this case you could use cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible in the way you request solely in javascript in-the browser (javascript cannot write to the source file).

You might have some luck however storing the definition of what checkboxes you've added in localStorage for example, then reload/redraw that same definition on reload of the page.

Comment: See @DarinDimitrov's link to get started with localStorage